# Subsetting a large dataset in R by Months

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am new to utilizing R and have a question regarding subsetting data in a large dataset into months. I am attempting to subset the data into different months starting with data from January. The package that I have loaded is openair.

I load the following file into regarding COVID data and have named it COVIDcases:

`COVIDcases <- read.csv("https://query.data.world/s/lysuc3ab7q3zubthc6paesbrsff3oo", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE);`

After loading the dataset I convert the date column to date instead of character

`COVIDcases$Date <- as.Date(paste(COVIDcases$Date), "%m/%d/%y")`

I then do a selectByDate statement to try and only analyze the January data.

`JanuaryCasesdata <-selectByDate(COVIDcases$Date, start = "2020-01-01", end = "2020-01-31")`

This is where I encounter a problem and keep getting the error:

`` "Error in `[.default`(mydata, , Names) : incorrect number of dimensions" ``

Is there anything in particular that I am doing wrong such as taking the wrong steps to subset the data?

Comment: Where did you find the `selectByDate()` function? Is it this one from the `openair` package? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openair/topics/selectByDate Or a different one?

Comment: Yes it is from the same openair package that you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `selectByDate()` states that the first argument is

> A data frame containing a `date` field in hourly or high resolution format.

That means that you need two changes to your code.

Firstly, the `Date` field needs to be named `date` (with a lower case `d`). you can do this when you convert from character. (`paste()` isn't doing anything here so you can get rid of it.)

```
COVIDcases$date <- as.Date(COVIDcases$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

Secondly, you need to pass the whole of your data frame, not just that one column.

```
JanuaryCasesdata <- selectByDate(COVIDcases, start = "2020-01-01", end = "2020-01-31")
```